# Upload failed: [Error: [storage/unknown] An unknown error has occurred

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I try to upload a "base64" image to Firebase by using React Native on iOS. But when I try to upload the image, I get following error:

Upload failed:  [Error: [storage/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.

What should I do, I have tried to change the rules, but I'am not sure if they are right. I have Uninstall firebase/Storage and reinstall it again, but I get the same error.

If I run npm install I get following warning:

> [!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/storage' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v12.3.0 but found v12.1.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

is anyone have clue of what I should do?

```
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const dataUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${result}`;
  
    filename.
    const childPath = `paintBoards/${
      auth().currentUser.uid
    }/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;

    const storageRef = storage().ref(childPath);
  
    const uploadTask = storageRef.putString(dataUrl, 'data_url');
  
     uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      setTransferred(
        Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
      );
    });
  
    try {
      await uploadTask;
      
      setUploading(false);
      Alert.alert(
        'Photo uploaded!',
        'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
      );
    } catch (err) {
      // TODO: Check value of `err.code` and handle appropriately.
      console.error('Upload failed: ', err);
      Alert.alert(
        'Photo upload failed!',
        'Your photo didn upload properly!'
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I had this exact problem an year ago. I don't remember well the solution, but it should be a format error with the base64 uri that your are trying to upload. Double check it

Comment: I found mine solution! check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927459/8405122

Comment: the problem was with the Firebase storage. I just reinstalled it.